# How to check if user input is inside of a Python list

Tags: python, sqlite, loops

I'm having trouble checking if the user input `s` is in the list i'm printing to the user. The list `rows` prints like `[(1, 'Data', 'match both vlan-profile'), (2, 'Data', 'match neither vlan-profile')]` and basically what I want to do is after the user is shown the list of profiles, to select the one they want to use based on the number at the beginning. So far what I have here keeps my loop going saying `"Sorry, please select a number listed above."`, so it's obviously not finding the 1 or 2 value in the lists. I appreciate any help with this!

```
def select_vlan():
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM vlan_prof')

    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        # row[i] each column in the table
        print(row[0],row[1],row[2])
```

^this prints 2 lines for the user to inspect:
"1 Data match both vlan-profile"
"2 Data match neither vlan-profile"

```
    while True:
        try:
            s = input("Enter number of VLAN profile you wish to use: ")
            print(s)
        except ValueError:
            print("Sorry, please select by number.")
            continue
        if s not in rows:
            print("Sorry, please select a number listed above.")
            continue
        else:
            #age was successfully parsed, and we're happy with its value.
            #we're ready to exit the loop.
            break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the column from your query to check is row[0] then set up an array for this

```
checker=[]
for row in rows:
  checker.append(row[0])
```

Then convert the input to an integer and use this later to check for the correct values

```
try:
   s = int(input("Enter number of VLAN profile you wish to use: "))
...

if s not in checker:
```

Comment: Works perfectly, after i convert s to an int. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```
lst = [(1, 'Data', 'match both vlan-profile'), (2, 'Data', 'match neither vlan-profile')]
s = input("Enter number of VLAN profile you wish to use: ")
if next(x for x in lst if s == x[0], None) is not None:
    # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is shown below:

```
rows = [(1, 'Data', 'match both vlan-profile'), (2, 'Data', 'match neither vlan-profile')]
row_checker = [x[0] for x in rows]      # Note This
while True:
        try:
            s = input("Enter number of VLAN profile you wish to use: ")
            print(s)
        except ValueError:
            print("Sorry, please select by number.")
            continue
        if int(s) not in row_checker:    # note this
            print("Sorry, please select a number listed above.")
            continue
        else:
            #age was successfully parsed, and we're happy with its value.
            #we're ready to exit the loop.
            break
```

What is happening is `rows` is a list of tuples and s is an integer. You are finding an integer in list of tuples and hence while loop does not break.

The solution shown above extracts the first element from each tuple into another list and you can use this for checking.

Note that **s is a string and you want an integer**, hence while comparing, you need to convert `s` from string to integer.

Let me know if it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Your test is not quite right. Also be sure you are testing type int == type int.

```
while True:
...
    if not [row for row in rows if int(s) == int(row[0])]:
        print("Sorry, please select a number listed above.")
        continue
```